# Why Kendo MVC Grid export excel function hiding all columns in excel file?

Tags: c#, html, excel, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have kendo mvc grid and basically all functions are correct but when i try to export my excel from my grid it's downloading excel but hiding all columns results weirdly

Here my grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Alerts>()
                .Name("grdWaterAlert").AutoBind(false)
                .HtmlAttributes("width: 100%;cellpadding:0;")
                .DataSource(d => d.Ajax().Read("GridWaterAlertBinding", "Dashboards"))
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(e => e.BelIdent).Title("Id").Width("auto");
                    columns.Bound(e => e.StationCode).Title("Station Code").Width("auto");
                    columns.Bound(e => e.StationName).Title("Station Name").Width("auto");
                    columns.Bound(e => e.BelTarih).Title("DateTime").ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(BelTarih, 'MM/dd/yyyy') #").ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("DateTime" + ": #=  kendo.toString(value, 'MM/dd/yyyy') #").Width("auto");
                    columns.Bound(e => e.BelInsTime).Title("Alert Time").ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(BelInsTime, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt') #").ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("DateTime" + ": #=  kendo.toString(value, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt') #").Width("auto");
                    columns.Bound(e => e.BelTankId).Title("Tank ID").Width("auto");
                    columns.Bound(e => e.ProductCode).Title("Product Code").Width("auto");
                    columns.Bound(e => e.BelAlarm).Title("Alarm").Width("auto");
                    columns.Bound(e => e.BelTotCapacity).Title("Total Capacity").Width("auto");
                    columns.Bound(e => e.BelWaterVol).Title("Water Volume").Width("auto");
                })
                .ToolBar(toolBar =>
                {
                    toolBar.Excel().HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "btnexcel" }).Text(" ").IconClass("k-i-excel");
                    toolBar.Custom().Text((string)ViewData["ClearFilter"]).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-button", id = "cleargrid", href = "#", onclick = "clearFiltersWaterLevel()" });
                })
                .Excel(excel => excel.FileName("WaterAlert.xlsx").Filterable(true))
                .Selectable()
                .Sortable()
                .AutoBind(false)
                .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                .Refresh(true)
                .PageSizes(true)
                .ButtonCount(5))
                .Filterable(filterable => filterable
                .Extra(false)
                .Operators(operators => operators
                .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                .StartsWith((string)ViewData["Startswith"])
                .Contains((string)ViewData["Contains"])
                ))
                )
                .Groupable()
                .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height("100%"))
                .Resizable(config =>
                {
                config.Columns(true);
                })
                .Reorderable(config =>
                {
                config.Columns(true);
                })
                .ColumnMenu()
            )
```

How can i handle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem myself i realised i gave all columns `.Width("auto")` and when Excel try to export grid checking column width and because of the `.Width("auto")` it cannot give automatic width than looks columns hide....

When i give width value everything looks perfect